# Retrofit Error Handling with different types of responses

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I have two different responses for two different scenarios. One scenario is that I get a JSONArray as a response

```
 [ {
        "type" : "cat",       
        "color": "black"
      }, 
      {
        "type" : "cat",
        "color": "white"
      } ]
```

this is the normal response that I am supposed to get. But If the response isnt available for the body that I am sending, I get the following response.

```
{ "message" : "response not available for this date" }
```

this is the post request that I have

```
@POST("user/userTimetable")
    fun getTypeApi(@HeaderMap headers: Map<String, String>, @Body body: ScheduleBody?) : Call <List<Type>>
```

When I get the latter response, I am getting a crash

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

How do I work with this type of response on kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

Retrofit won't predict the response, so either you set the result type to `ResponseBody` with an object type or change your backend to send a default case that implements the error message and the data.

Answer (score -2):

> I once had this issue, please follow the code below

1. create a model class called ErrorResponse which will return the Data above and modify to show only your message response.

[image]

2. create a class called ErrorResponseService which will be used to map the ErrorMessage to the returning respose.

[image]

3. Then do this implementation in your Retrofit call to get the error message when your response fails.

[image]

Comment: Try not to use Screenshots to show the code.

Comment: Where exactly do we do step 3? Its not really clear

Comment: use it in your onResponse callback, once your check if response.isSuccessful then user the above code to map your response to display your error message

Comment: Because of the crash that I mentioned, its not going into the onResponse callback. and it goes into the onFailure callback. I tried changing the return type of getTypeApi to the ErrorResponse and then it was going into the onResponse callback.